# Sinon - how to stub nested function?

Tags: node.js, request, mocha.js, sinon, chai

Apologies if this is a simple question, I'm relatively new to Node and Sinon.  I'm struggling trying to figure out how to assert that a nested asynchronous function was called in Nodejs.

I'm using mocha, chai, sinon, and request (https://github.com/request/request)  but think I'm missing something basic on the stubbing part.

Example inside my_app.js -

```
var request = require('request');

function MyModule() {
};

MyModule.prototype.getTicker = function(callback) {
    request('http://example.com/api/ticker', function(error, response) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};

exports.mymodule = new MyModule();
```

Inside the test.  I'm trying to stub out the call to request and provide some dummy data to return.  But I keep getting an error "request is not defined" on the line where I"m creating the stub.

```
var myApp = require('../my_app.js')
    ,assert = require("assert")
    ,chai = require('chai')
    ,sinon = require('sinon')
    ,expect = chai.expect;

describe('mymodule object', function() {

    var mymodule = myApp.mymodule;

    before(function(done) {
        sinon.stub(request).yields(null, JSON.stringify({
            price: '100 USD'
        }));
        done();
    });

    it('getTicker function should call request on example ticker', function(done) {
        mymodule.getTicker(function(error, result){
            request.called.should.be.equal(true);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

I know I can assign sinon.stub(objname, "funcname") or sinon.stub("funcname"), but those only set the  outer object , I'm trying to stub the function request which is inside the function getTicker.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Maybe I need to use a spy as well (but how?)  Or is there a better approach to test the above getTicker function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are receiving the undefined message because the `request` variable is unknown within the scope of your test. However, even if you were to correct this and assign the `request` library to the variable, you would still receive an error as sinon requires a method on any provided object in order to create a stub.

The consequence of such is that the `request` function itself cannot be stubbed as it does not exist on an object but as a function onto which other methods are defined. In order to support testability, therefore, it'd be preferable to forgo using `request` directly in your code, and instead use its attached methods which can then be stubbed. For example:

**my_app.js**

```
MyModule.prototype.getTicker = function(callback) {
  request.get('http://example.com/api/ticker', function(error, response) {
    ...
  });
};
```

**my_test.js**

```
var request = require('request');

before(function() {
  sinon.stub(request, 'get').yields(null, JSON.stringify({price: '100 USD'}));
});

it('getTicker function should call request on example ticker', function() {
  mymodule.getTicker();
  request.get.called.should.be.equal(true);
});
```

(Note that running mocha asynchronously is un-necessary when a stub is synchronous).

Comment: Ok awesome, didn't think to use the get method on this. Now I can also use a spy to verify the callback was invoked I think.

Comment: Ahh yup I can verify the callback was called.  but I'm using a little different syntax `mymodule.getTicker(callback);`  `request.get.should.have.been.called;`  and  `request.get.should.have.been.called;`   Thanks a ton!